# Ptrace allows to write to executable program segment, but process_vm_writev doesn't

Tags: c, linux, low-level, ptrace

While experimenting with editing opcodes of running process on Linux with C language, I found out that I can't to edit program opcodes by PID with `process_vm_writev`, but using `ptrace` and `pwrite` I can do it. `process_vm_writev` returns -1 and `errno` says "Bad address". But when I use ptrace with same address it successes. I run program as root. Is it an issue of GNU/Linux and should I open an issue on GitHub? Code for `process_vm_writev` (without includes to be short):

```
ssize_t write_pmem(pid_t pid, off_t addr, void* value, size_t size) {
    struct iovec local[1];
    local[0].iov_base = value;
    local[0].iov_len = size;
    struct iovec remote[1];
    remote[0].iov_base = (void*)addr;
    remote[0].iov_len = size;

    return process_vm_writev(pid, local, 1, remote, 1, 0);
}

int main() {
    pid_t pid;
    off_t opcode_ptr = 0x45B5A7;

    printf("PID: ");
    scanf("%d", &pid);

    char nops[5] = {0x90, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90, 0x90};
    ssize_t res = write_pmem(pid, opcode_ptr, &nops, sizeof(nops));

    printf("%ld\n%s", res, strerror(errno));
    /* and it prints:
       -1
       Bad address */
    return 0;
}
```

`/proc/PID/maps` says that `0x45B5A7` is `00406000-004f0000 r-xp 00006000` for that process (no write rights) but I think it's still writable for the root.

I want to use new process_vm Linux API, so I want to fix that code. Any ideas?

Comment: [The man page says](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/process_vm_writev.2.html) *Permission to read from or write to another process is governed by a ptrace access mode `PTRACE_MODE_ATTACH_REALCREDS` check; see ptrace(2).*  The example in the man page doesn't attach to that PID with `ptrace`, but you might need to if you want to write into read-only memory.  Maybe I'm misinterpreting that and it's only talking about being allowed to write remote memory at all, not page permissions.

Comment: The NOTES in the man page says: "*These system calls were designed to permit fast message passing by allowing messages to be exchanged with a single copy operation (rather than
       the double copy that would be required when using, for example, shared memory or pipes).*" - So they're designed for message-passing, not debugging.  I wouldn't expect there to be any way to write read-only memory with it.

Answer (score 3):

The reason it works with ptrace but not with process_vm_writev is that ptrace writes to memory in the kernel and the kernel uses a different page table with different access permissions than the usermode process. Whereas process_vm_writev copies bytes from one userspace address space to another using the usermode page tables.

Comment: Is that true, that `process_vm_writev` uses `switch_to()` to make the target process the `current` one for this core, or otherwise sets the hardware to use its page-table instead of the one from the caller of this function?

Comment: If that was true, that it uses the target process's page tables, how does it read the original process's memory?  Via a kernel mapping?  I think it's more likely that `process_vm_writev` just checks permissions against the target process's page tables using software to decide whether to return `-EFAULT` or not (vs. `ptrace` always allowing a write, perhaps triggering copy-on-write e.g. for `.text` of an executable).  Then in both cases write to the target process's memory through a kernel mapping of that physical page.

Comment: If you read this https://lwn.net/Articles/789153/ you see it says, "This call is much like mmap(), in that it creates a new memory mapping in the calling process's address space; that mapping (possibly) starts at dst_addr and is len bytes long. It will be populated by the contents of the memory range starting at src_addr in the process identified by pid. There are a couple of flags defined: PVMMAP_FIXED to specify an exact address for the mapping and PVMMAP_FIXED_NOREPLACE to prevent a fixed mapping from replacing an existing mapping at the destination address.", granted that's an early draft.

Comment: The text you quoted is about `process_vm_mmap` which makes shared mappings (by modifying page tables, not accessing data through them), unlike `process_vm_writev` which actually copies.  It looks like the proposed `process_vm_mmap` didn't make it into the mainline kernel (at least not 6.2 on my Arch Linux desktop), but `process_vm_readv/writev` did.

Comment: Ah you're right, I missed that bit. It does say, "Both calls copy data between the local address space (as described by the lvec array) and the remote space (described by rvec); they do so without moving the data through kernel space. For certain kinds of traffic they are quite efficient, but there are exceptions, especially as the amount of copied data gets large. " in reference to process_vm_writev though which implies it's not using kernel page tables. It doesn't describe how it actually does achieve it though. I will do some more digging.

Comment: `process_vm_readv/writev` copy directly between user-space page of different processes, not bouncing into a kernel buffer.  There is no page-table where both the source and destination have user-space addresses.  So the kernel has to manually check the mappings of at least one process (`current` or the remote) to check permissions and to find the physical address, and thus be able to access it through a kernel mapping.  It seems implausible to me that these system calls would change the HW page tables (e.g. x86 CR3 register) when that doesn't make anything easier.

Comment: It's clearly true that `process_vm_writev` does check for writeability in the other process's logical mappings, but the way your answer phrases it makes it sound like hardware is doing that.  The kernel does (in software) traverse the HW page table data structure of the target process, or possibly not if it can get physical-page addresses (and thus kernel virtual addresses) from another data structure.  (A page table includes a kernel-only mapping of all physical memory in the high half of virtual address space, as well the user-space mappings in the low half.)